# How to use Binary Search on array of string

Tags: c, struct, binary-search

I have to write a program only using things that i've learned in class, where I register information from a car, sort it and use the Binary Search to search for a cars' license plate. If the license plate is found, print all the info about that especific car, If don't pritnt "Not found" and **returns -1**. All works fine until the Binary Search, the problem is that it won't find the license plate, It always returns -1.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_CARRO 5  // DEFINE TAMANHO DA STRUCT

typedef struct   // STRUCT
{
    char placa[50];
    char marca[50];
    char modelo[50];
    char ano[50];
    char valordiaria[50];
} carro;
carro car[MAX_CARRO];

int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{    
    carro *carroA = (carro *)a;
    carro *carroB = (carro *)b;   

    return strcmp(carroA, carroB);
}

int main()
{
    int x=0; //COUNTER

    for(x=0; x<MAX_CARRO; x++) // CAR REGISTER
    {    
        printf("\nCarro: %d", (x+1));

        printf("\nPlaca: ");
        scanf("%s",car[x].placa);    

        printf("Marca: ");
        scanf("%s",car[x].marca);    

        printf("Modelo: ");
        scanf("%s",car[x].modelo);    

        printf("Ano: ");
        scanf("%s",car[x].ano);    

        printf("Valor da diaria: ");
        scanf("%s",car[x].valordiaria);    
    }    

    qsort (car, MAX_CARRO, sizeof(carro), compare);  // USO DO QSORT

    printf("\n\nSTRUCT ORDENADA: \n");
    for(x=0; x<MAX_CARRO; x++) // MOSTRA NA TELA A STRUCT ORDENADA
    {
        printf("\n\n\nCarro: %d", (x+1));
        printf("\nPlaca: %s", car[x].placa);
        printf("\nMarca: %s", car[x].marca);
        printf("\nModelo: %s", car[x].modelo);
        printf("\nAno: %s", car[x].ano);
        printf("\nValor da diaria: %s", car[x].valordiaria);
    }

    char k[10];

    //           *****BINARY SEARCH******    
    printf("\n\n\n*****BUSCA DE PLACAS*****\n\n\n\n");
    printf("Digite a placa que deseja procurar: \n");
    scanf("%s", &k);

//              ***PROBLEM***     

    int low, high, mid;

    low=0;
    high = MAX_CARRO-1;
    while(low<=high)
    {
        mid = (low+high)/2;

        if (strcmp(k, car[mid].placa)<0)
            high=mid-1;    

        else if (strcmp(k, car[mid].placa)>0)
            low=mid+1;    

        else
        {
            printf("\nPlaca: %s", car[mid].placa);
            printf("\nMarca: %s", car[mid].marca);
            printf("\nModelo: %s", car[mid].modelo);
            printf("\nAno: %s", car[mid].ano);
            printf("\nValor da diaria: %s", car[mid].valordiaria);
        }    

        printf("\n\n****Not found****\n\n\n");
        return -1; //     
    }    
}
```

Comment: The compiler should shout warnings at you. At the very least for that [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) call in `compare`. You do know that [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) is for comparing *strings*, and neither`carroA` nor `carroB` are strings. You should really listen to what the compiler tells you.

Comment: As a side note, if you manage to use `qsort` correctly you may as well use `bsearch` too, it is very similar. If this is for school, then at least you can use it to verify that your implementation of binary search is correct.

Comment: `scanf("%s", &k);` You should check the expected type of parameter. And what type you provide. Also you do not have any possible execution flow in your loop, that does not lead to `return -1`. You never execute the loop a second time.

Comment: and the casts to `(carro *)` in `compare()` are completely unnecessary - that's the whole point of `void *`, a type introduced to the language standard just 29 years ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have few bugs.

First one is in your compare() function. You can not write this line

```
return strcmp(carroA, carroB);
```

Because strcmp is working just with char* types, and carroA and carroB are of type carro*. You should place

```
 return strcmp(carroA->placo, carroB->placo);
```

Now you will sort your structures by the value of placo.

Now lets take a look at your main function.

First bug in main() is in your line of code

```
  scanf("%s", &k);
```

You don't need &, you should make it like this

```
  scanf("%s",k);
```

Second bug is in your while() loop in the last line

```
  return -1;
```

This is a huge thing because main() will return -1. If you want main() to exit like an error occurred you should write return 1;

Maybe you should use one variable to determine weather you have found what you was looking for in your binary search

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_CARRO 5  // DEFINE TAMANHO DA STRUCT

typedef struct   // STRUCT
{
    char placa[50];
    char marca[50];
    char modelo[50];
    char ano[50];
    char valordiaria[50];
} carro;
carro car[MAX_CARRO];

int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{    
    carro *carroA = (carro *)a;
    carro *carroB = (carro *)b;   

    return strcmp(carroA->placa, carroB->placa);
}

int main()
{
    int x=0; //COUNTER

    for(x=0; x<MAX_CARRO; x++) // CAR REGISTER
    {    
        printf("\nCarro: %d", (x+1));

        printf("\nPlaca: ");
        scanf("%s",car[x].placa);    

        printf("Marca: ");
        scanf("%s",car[x].marca);    

        printf("Modelo: ");
        scanf("%s",car[x].modelo);    

        printf("Ano: ");
        scanf("%s",car[x].ano);    

        printf("Valor da diaria: ");
        scanf("%s",car[x].valordiaria);    
    }    

    qsort (car, MAX_CARRO, sizeof(carro), compare);  // USO DO QSORT

    printf("\n\nSTRUCT ORDENADA: \n");
    for(x=0; x<MAX_CARRO; x++) // MOSTRA NA TELA A STRUCT ORDENADA
    {
        printf("\n\n\nCarro: %d", (x+1));
        printf("\nPlaca: %s", car[x].placa);
        printf("\nMarca: %s", car[x].marca);
        printf("\nModelo: %s", car[x].modelo);
        printf("\nAno: %s", car[x].ano);
        printf("\nValor da diaria: %s", car[x].valordiaria);
    }

    char k[10];

    //           *****BINARY SEARCH******    
    printf("\n\n\n*****BUSCA DE PLACAS*****\n\n\n\n");
    printf("Digite a placa que deseja procurar: \n");
    scanf("%s", k);

//              ***PROBLEM***     

    int low, high, mid;

    low=0;
    high = MAX_CARRO-1;
    int found=0;
    while(low<=high && !found)
    {
        mid = (low+high)/2;

        if (strcmp(k, car[mid].placa)<0)
            high=mid-1;    

        else if (strcmp(k, car[mid].placa)>0)
            low=mid+1;    

        else
        {
            found = 1;
            printf("\nPlaca: %s", car[mid].placa);
            printf("\nMarca: %s", car[mid].marca);
            printf("\nModelo: %s", car[mid].modelo);
            printf("\nAno: %s", car[mid].ano);
            printf("\nValor da diaria: %s", car[mid].valordiaria);
        }    


    } 
    if(!found)
        printf("\n\n****Not found****\n\n\n");
 return 0; //
}
```

Comment: Instead of exiting main with `return 1` - use `return EXIT_FAILURE`

Comment: return 1 is equivalent to return EXIT_FAILURE , 
return 0 is equivalent to return EXIT_SUCCESS

Comment: My mistake - was in the process of editing the comment